# Login Success but Redirect fails

Tags: abp

I am using Blazor WebServer with Identity Server template, downloaded from ABP.IO

When run locally, it all works fine. Login is success and able to see the post login page.

Once deployed to Azure App Service, Identity page shows correctly and even able to login. On the Blazor page, click on login, enter credentials, redirects back to the logged out page, but seems session is created, and login button shown. there is no error logged in the log files and console also has no errors.

Redis is running as Azure Redis Cache and there are no reported errors. I have deployed to below URL on Azure using the default template. Nothing confidential so I can share. The credentials are also the default credentials for abp.io.

Blazor: https://shoutout-core-dev.azurewebsites.net/
Identity: https://shoutout-identity-dev.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no error already. Because when I make a request via swagger, I can access the necessary user information. As you stated, actually the session was created.

[image]

But there is a problem with the UI. To test the problem, after publishing the application in your local, can you run `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with the `Production` environment variable?

In addition, we need your ABP version information and your steps while publishing in local so that we can repeat the error.

Comment: I had reverted to using MVC/Razor instead of Blazor. You are right that it is the UI that was problematic. With MVC it is working fine.  I was using abp 4.4 and Blazor Server. In local it was running fine, just when publishing to azure app, i had the error. After reverting to abp4.4 and MVC, it is working fine both in local and azure.

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

this problem probably occurs on chrome. If you try to use firefox, you will pass the problem.Also, you can check this link for the fix on the chrome :

> https://community.abp.io/posts/patch-for-chrome-login-issue-identityserver4-samesite-cookie-problem-weypwp3n